# How to allow an IP (ipv6) address using ufw?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, ipv6

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I want to block all connections except some IP addresses. I ran these commands

```
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow ssh
ufw enable
ufw allow from 1.2.3.4
```

and it's working fine for me, But now i want to allow a ipv6 address and i'm using this command.

```
ufw allow from 2405:204:108e:650c:10cb:11ea:bb8f:3937
```

but it's not working

Comment: Have a look at /etc/default/ufw. It's policy is probably drop for ipv6.

Comment: can any one help me, how to allow IPv6 any alternative solution?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. All I get is `Rule added (v6)`. More information is needed. What went wrong?

Comment: Did you use `sudo` `ufw` always requires this?

Comment: Notice that IPv6 devices usually have many IPv6 addresses, where it generate new ones for reaching out from the machine.  But usually have one that is constantly the same. So in case that the machine have many IPv6 addresses, choose the right one.

Comment: And "not working" isn't a good question.  What isn't working as you expect it to work need to be said.

Answer (score 7):

`man ufw` is the answer (at line 139), the manual mention this:

```
...
         ufw deny proto tcp from 2001:db8::/32 to any port 25

       This  will  deny all traffic from the IPv6 2001:db8::/32 to tcp port 25
       on this host. Note that IPv6 must be enabled  in  /etc/default/ufw  for
       IPv6 firewalling to work.
...
```

Since the OP not mentioning more detail about his difficulties, I hope this answer may help you to create IPV6 ufw rules

Answer (score 0):

### Are you sure that this is the IP address you want to allow?

Trusting Google search?

### Doesn't work

I noticed that when I googled for "my ip", then **Google** showed that I have an **IPv6** address - that ***didn't work*** for access with ufw.

### Works

When I checked my IP with **another site**, then I had an **IPv4** address - that ***worked*** for access with ufw.

- Shows IPv4: https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/
- Shows IPv4 and IPv6: https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Answer (score -3):

## To allow an IP(ipv6) address using ufw

1. First enable the IPv6 in `/etc/default/ufw`. Probably first 4-5 lines describe what you need to do to have ufw support IPv6.

```
  # Set to yes to apply rules to support IPv6 (no means only IPv6 on loopback
  # accepted). You will need to 'disable' and then 'enable' the firewall for
  # the changes to take affect.
  IPV6=yes
```

If you see `IPV6=no`, then edit the file to change it to `IPV6=yes` and save it.

> $ sudo nano /etc/default/ufw

2. Now, Do either a `ufw Disable-then-Enable` OR `ufw Reload`

   - ufw Disable-then-Enable

     > $ sudo ufw disable 
     >  $ sudo ufw enable
   - ufw Reload

     > $ sudo ufw reload

     NOTE : A server/system Restart may be required for changes to take effect.
3. Now, Re-add all your existing firewall rules so that the IPv6 rules get added.

> $ sudo ufw allow proto ipv6 from x.x.x.x

Comment: Enabling proto 41 will not solve the problem.

Comment: errors "Invalid port with protocol 'ipv6'", may want to revise this answer

Comment: The 'proto` directive is for `tcp` or `udp`.  If you add an IPv6 or IPv4 address to the ufw line, it will add that rule only to IPv6 resp. IPv4.  No need to tell ufw which IP version to use.  If no IP address is mentioned, it will add the rule to both.

You also probably want to allow IPv6 network and not one IPv6 address.  Unless it is a server.  But those usually have a static IPv6 address (that doesn't have FF:FE in the middle of the host part of the address, which means it is auto generated).